# underscore.js template not picking up jquery data-roles and classes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, backbone.js, underscore.js

I am using an underscore.js  template to load my html data where  I have used jquery data roles and classes in the template itself.But unlike in other html elements where I have used the jquery data-roles and classes,the template when rendered doesnt looks like the other jquery widgets.

This is the template used.

```
    <div data-role="fieldcontain" class="populate-category-input">
        <input name="" id="populate-category-input-id" placeholder="category" value="<%-category%>"
        type="text" data-mini="true" disabled="disabled">
        <label><%-category%></label>
    </div>
    <div data-role="fieldcontain" class="populate-amount-input">
        <input name="" id="populate-amount-input-id"  value="<%-amount%>" type="text"
        data-mini="true" disabled="disabled">
        <label><%-amount%></label>
    </div>
    <div data-role="fieldcontain" class="populate-description-input">
        <input name="" id="populate-description-input-id" placeholder="description" value="<%-description%>"
        type="text" data-mini="true" disabled="disabled">
        <label><%-description%></label>
    </div>
    <a id="populate-edit-id" data-role="button" data-inline="true" href="#" data-icon="edit"
    data-iconpos="notext" class="reset">
    </a>
    <a id="populate-delete-id" data-role="button" data-inline="true" href="#" data-icon="delete"
    data-iconpos="notext" class="done">
    </a>
```

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using jQuery Mobile. Aftet you render the template you should trigger the `create` method of the page

```
$("#pageid").trigger('create')
```

In this way your widgets will be initialized.